# Probability for a pairwise independent family

Tags: probability

Let $\mathcal{H}_{m,k}$ be a collection of functions from $\{0,1\}^m$ to $\{0,1\}^k$. We say that $\mathcal{H}_{m,k}$ is *pairwise independent* if for every $x,x' \in \{0,1\}^m$ with $x \neq x'$ and for every $y,y' \in \{0,1\}^k$ we have that

$$\Pr_{h \in_R \mathcal{H}_{m,k}}[h(x) = y \, \land \, h(x') = y'] = \frac{1}{2^{2k}}.$$

The notation $h \in_R \mathcal{H}_{m,k}$ means that $h$ is chosen uniformly at random from the family.

Let $S \subseteq \{0,1\}^m$. I am asked to prove that if $\mathcal{H}_{m,k}$ is a pairwise independent collection of functions and $|S| > 2^{k}$ then

$$\Pr_{h \in_R \mathcal{H}_{m,k}}[\exists \, x,y \in S : x \neq y \, \land \, h(x)=h(y)] = 1.$$

My initial idea was to define a random variable $N$ witch counts the number of collisions (i.e. the number of  distinct $\, x,y \in S$ such that $h(x)=h(y)$). And then my idea was to calculate $\Pr[N \geq 1]$. If I prove that this probability is strictly greater than $0$ whenever $|S| > 2^{k}$, I solve it; but I don't see how to calculate or bound this probability.

Another option would be to calculate $E[N]$.

Comment: There are two $n$s (one in the first displayed equation, one in $\mathcal{H}_{n,k}$ in the line before the second displayed equation), but $n$ is never introduced. Are those typos?

Comment: @joriki Yes, corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @Saad You are right, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a probability problem at all, but rather a combinatoric problem. Since $\mathcal H_{m,k}$ is a finite set, stating
$$\Pr_{h \in_R \mathcal{H}_{m,k}}[\exists \, x,y \in S : x \neq y \, \land \, h(x)=h(y)] = 1$$
is equivalent to stating
$$\forall h\in\mathcal H_{m,k},\quad\exists x,y\in S:x\neq y,\quad h(x)=h(y).$$

This is just the pigeonhole principle: $h$ is defined as a function from $\{0,1\}^m$ to $\{0,1\}^k$, so in particular it is a function $h:S\rightarrow\{0,1\}^k$. By hypothesis, $|S|>2^k=|\{0,1\}^k|$, so there exist two distinct elements $x,y$ of $S$ such that $h(x)=h(y)$.